# While loop, sum the fifth, tenth, fifteenth...etc number

Tags: c#, while-loop, iteration

Example of what needs to be done:

[image: Example of what needs to be done]

"Several numbers are entered (the input again ends with 0). Determine and print the sum of the 5th,
10th, 15th number, etc."

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (number != 0)
        {
            if (number > 0 && counter % 5 == 0)
            {
                counter++;
                sum = sum + number;
            }
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the 5th, 10th, 15th ... number is = {0}", sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a nice first answer. tips: you can write `sum += number;` instead of `sum = sum + number;` :)

Comment: Well, what *goes* whrong? What do you get? You only show what you expect but not what you get instead.

Comment: If you are comfortable with LINQ, https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#takeevery may be of interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem: you increment the `counter` only if `% 5 == 0` but it never reaches that value. As you can see your starting value is:

```
int counter = 0;
```

So the second part of the if condition will evaluate to `false` in the first iteration and all subsequent iterations, because the variable never gets the chance to change. It remains at `0` in all iterations

Solution: put the incrementing line outside of the if-clause.
This way you are actually counting the numbers of input numbers and thus you can identify whether it is the 5-th, 10-th, 15-th ...

Since you intend to count the input numbers I would suggest to put the

```
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

as the first line in the while loop. Then you can count up and after that you should evaluate wether this number is the 5-th, 10-th, 15-th ... element:

```
while (number != 0)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    counter++;

    if (number > 0 && counter % 5 == 0)
    {
        sum = sum + number;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Inspired by the comment by [PaulF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3070060/paulf) :

> I would assume that the counter should only be incremented if (number > 0).

To be correct in detail of your requirements you would need to make an extra if-clause to check for this case. But as `0`  is the neutral element in an addition it does not make a difference to the calculated sum. So the code should still produce the desired outcome

EDIT 2:

If your intention was also to not allow negative numbers then you should split your if clause into two and increment the counter only if the entered number is higher than `0`. Afterwards you can check whether the current element is a candidate to be added to the sum:

```
while (number != 0)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number > 0 )
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 5 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + number;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Please no negative numbers!");
    }
}
```

Comment: getting numbers should be in while loop too

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani it is in the while loop

Comment: @MongZhu: From the original code I would assume that the counter should only be incremented if (number > 0).

Comment: @PaulF that sounds correct, but since `0` is the neutral element in an addition it does not make a difference to the calculated sum. But your comment is valid. I will incorporate this into my answer

Comment: @MongZhu: entering any negative number would be valid input though, which would affect the result compared to the original code. I would split the if clause in two - with the check for every fifth number nested in the check for positive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment counter before if statment

```
Counter++
If (counter % 5 == 0) { 
...
```